# Asymptotic notation understanding

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I am trying to understand these equations. I have to identify which is wrong but I really want to understand how to do that.

```
1. $\theta(n)+O(n)=\omega(n)$
2. $O(n)+\sigma(n)=\theta(n)$
3. $\theta(n)+O(n)=O(n)$
4. $f(n)=O(n)$ implies $g(n)=\omega(f(n))$
```

I know that You have to read

$$\theta(n)+O(n)=\Omega(n)$$
as follows: if in my main I have 2 methods

```
main(){
m1();
m2();
}
```

and the running time of method m1 is \tetha(n) and the running time of m2 is O(n),
can I say that the running time of the main is \Omega(n)?

I think that the third is wrong.. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, since even if `m2` takes less than `O(n)`, the asymptotic running time of `m1` still has the lower bound because of the tight bound.

**Edit:** #1 is the reason behind it